# Can't get RTKLIB to use an external geoid

Tags: gps, geodesy, rtklib, geodetic

I want to write the results of processing a Rinex file using geodetic heights, and an external geoid from Spain's geographic institute IGN.

I have downloaded the geoid files from their FTP in text format from ftp://ftp.geodesia.ign.es/geoide/ascii/ with .txt and .asc extensions, and in binary GRD format (ftp://ftp.geodesia.ign.es/geoide/GRD/EGM08_REDNAP.grd), but none of them seems to work, and I am getting the exact same results as with RNX2RTKP default's geoid (EGM96, 1ºx1º), while I would expect to see a significant difference in height.

In order to tell RTKLIB that I want to use the external geoid, I run the program as follows:

```
rnx2rtkp.e -p 0 -k config_file.conf rinex_file.obs brdc_orbits.obs -o output_file.sol
```

where config_file.conf has only de following lines:

```
out-height         =geodetic
file-geoidfile     =geoid_filename
```

and geoid_filename is the .asc, .txt or .grd file.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not providing the file in the correct format, or should I set something else in the config file?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `out_geoid` option.  My working file looks like:

```
...
out-height         =geodetic   # (0:ellipsoidal,1:geodetic)
out-geoid          =egm96      #(0:internal,1:egm96,2:egm08_2.5,3:egm08_1,4:gsi2000)
...
file-geoidfile     =Z:\Users\drf\Work\RTKLIB\JUNK\WW15MGH.DAC
...
```

If you look at the RTKLIB manual, it identifies the geoid as internal, or four  specific GEOIDs.  I think other files would need to match one of these formats:

- A 15"x15" EGM96 WWMGH.DAC file from  http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/binary/binarygeoid.html 
  ( Specifically http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/binary/WW15MGH.DAC )
- The 1"x1" and 2.5"x2.5" EGM2008 small endian files from http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/egm08_wgs84.html (Specifically http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/Und_min1x1_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree_SE.gz and http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/Und_min2.5x2.5_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree_SE.gz )
- The gsigeome.ver4 from http://vldb.gsi.go.jp/sokuchi/geoid/download/down.html (I haven't tried this)

I cannot tell if EGM08-REDNAP geoid is equivalent to a subset of the EGM2008 1"x1" file above or not.  If you have a regional/local geoid model, I don't think RTKLIB will parse it, you might be better off solving for an ellipsoidal heights and then converting to your datum externally.  Or maybe you could patch it into a copy of the global egm08_1 file and use that.